# Jmeter - What is the functioning of "Per User" checkbox under Throughput Controller?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I need to divide the load on my application with some percentages i.e. Login Module - 60%, Accounts - 10%, Other Modules - 30%. After few research i find a option under Throughput Controller section in jmeter using which i can control these percentages. I find one checkbox there named "per user". Now i am not getting this check box.

As per blazemeter blog [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) i tried one scenario as below with "Per user" checkbox **checked**.

- Select "Total Execution" from dropdown.
- Marked Throughput as 40.
- Threads used - 10, Loop count 1

Now, as per the blog specific transactions should execute for 400 times. but there was **Zero** execution for that transaction.

I tried another scenario with "Per user" checkbox **checked**.

- Select "Total Execution" from dropdown.
- Marked Throughput as 60.
- Threads used - 10, Loop count 1

Now, as per the blog specific transactions should execute for 600 times. but it executed 10 times.

Can any experts out there share what am i doing wrong here? Or there is some more clarity needed how this checkbox works.

Comment: Got my answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281778/jmeter-what-is-the-functioning-of-per-user-checkbox-under-throughput-control